Favicon.ico отсутствует размером 32x32 48x48, хотя заявлен
Прописал favicon:
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "57x57"  href= "/apple-icon-57x57.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "60x60"  href= "/apple-icon-60x60.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "72x72"  href= "/apple-icon-72x72.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "76x76"  href= "/apple-icon-76x76.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "114x114"  href= "/apple-icon-114x114.png" > 
<link  rel= " apple-touch-icon"  size= "120x120"  href= "/apple-icon-120x120.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "144x144"  href= "/apple-icon-144x144.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "152x152"  href= "/apple-icon-152x152.png" > 
<link  rel= "apple-touch-icon"  size= "180x180"  href= "/apple-icon-180x180.png" > 
<link  rel= "icon"  type= "image/png"  size= "192x192"   href= "/android-icon-192x192.png" > 
<link  rel= "icon"  type= "image/png"  size= "96x96"  href= "/favicon-96x96.png" > 
<link  rel= "manifest"  href= "/manifest.json" > 
<link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" sizes = "16x16" href = "/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel = "icon" type = "image/png" sizes = "32x32" href = "/favicon-32x32.png">
<meta  name= "msapplication-TileColor"  content= "#ffffff" > 
<meta  name= "msapplication-TileImage"  content= "/ms-icon-144x144.png" > 
<meta  name= "theme-color"  content = "#ffffff" >   
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/favicon.svg" color="orange">

Но получаю ошибку "favicon.ico is missing some icons of recommended sizes (16x16, 32x32)", знатоки, подскажите в чем проблема?

Имеется в виду файл favicon.ico в корне файла, а не png изображения.
